# SVM low accuracy but significant p value

Tags: svm

I'm also new at doing SVM...

We have a data set of about 50 (25 in each group). We are trying to identify babies at a high risk of developing a disorder from babies that are low risk for developing a disorder. When I run SVM (LOOCV, linear kernal, ttest filtering), I'm getting really low accuracy levels (i.e. 24% in one case), but with statistically significant p-values. Can anyone help me understand why this is happening/what this could mean?

Thanks!

Comment: how do you calculate the p-values?

Comment: Also, you're saying that you're getting worse than random chance (50%) accuracy?  So, based on your high level description: if you're doing a two-tailed t-test then you might be picking up significance in the wrong direction.  A one-tailed t-test might give you the proper (high) p-values you are expecting.

Comment: Some option is that your data contains meaningful information, but only enough to get a ~25% accuracy. Do you have any clue it is actually really low?

Comment: I'm running these analyses in MATLAB with the spider code and a wrapper written by someone else a while back. The code shows p_acc: binopdf(tp + tn, tp+fp+tn+fn, 0.5) (tp/fp = true/false pos & tn/fn = true/false neg)

I am not sure if it is truly that low. When I rerun the analyses on the 50 subjects using 100 or 200 features instead of 50 features, the accuracy goes up quite a bit. Not sure how to interpret this...

Comment: I'm a bit rusty on my MATLAB...does the binopdf function there test the hypothesis that arguments 1 and 2 are significantly different from each other?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that you don't have enough data to reliably use an SVM. That, and, in my experience, they tend to perform best with high-dimensional data (e.g., 1000s of variables). How many predictor variable are you working with?

As a more direct answer to your p-value question, you should look at what the p-value is actually associated with--are you saying that it's associated with the accuracy statistic, or something else?

Comment: Kyle - thanks, I have heard this as well and have been wondering if this might be part of the problem. So, what we are doing is taking two groups of 25 subjects (high risk and low risk for a disorder) and looking at various ROIs & their connections in the brain. Our matrices are 247x247x50. I posted a comment above to answer some other questions that may provide you with a little more information. 

I believe the p value is associated with the accuracy statistic.